# Replacing '\' character in a Java String

Tags: java

I have a java string with `"\\"` character (extra `'\'` for escaping). I want to replace all the occurence of `"\\"` to `"&#x5c;"`. Any idea how it can be done? `str.replaceAll("\\", "&#x5c;")` does not work. The problem is in replacing the `\` character.

Comment: Is your string 'my\string' or 'my\\string'. Do you want to replace one or two slashes?

Comment: "my\string" is invalid in java. its definitely "my\\string".

Comment: I'm not talking about the java string. If in java you have String x = "my\\string", the actual logical string is "my\string", right?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore thats correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str.replaceAll("\\\\", "&#x5c;")
```

"\" means \ cause of \ is an escape symbol

heh, even stackoverflow parser converts \ \ (without spaces) to single \ :-))

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see `Matcher.replaceAll`. Use
>   `Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)` to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired.

Comment: Oh irony... fixed the escaping issues in your answer!